# python re, extract values between commas

Tags: python, regex

Why next regular expression returns empty strings among 'a' and 'b'?

```
In [48]: pat = re.compile(".*?(?=,|$)")

In [49]: it = pat.findall('a,b')

In [50]: it
Out[50]: ['a', '', 'b', '']
```

How can I extract substrings between commas?

EDIT:
I am curious how to do it using regular expressions.

EDIT:
Regular expression should successfully extract tree empty string in this input ",,".

Comment: why don't you split on `,`? (also, * means 0 or more, so ...)

Comment: I would like to understand how to do it using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.*?` first matches `a` because the next character is a `,`.
- The regex engine is now at the position before the `,`.
- Now, `.*?` matches the empty string before the `,` (because a zero-length match is allowed by the asterisk).
- The regex engine advances one character after a zero-length match (it has to, or it would get stuck here forever).
- `.*?` now matches `b` because we're at the end of the string.
- The regex engine is now at the end of the string.
- `.*?` matches the empty string before the end of the string.
- The string is exhausted. The regex engine ends.

The best solution would be to simply split on commas.

If you insist on using a regex, it's a bit more complicated, since (according to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.findall)), `re.findall()` includes empty matches unless they touch the *beginning* of another match. That means we have to use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of the lookahead you used.

This in turn means that we can't check for the delimiter and the start-of-string anchor in the same assertion since Python doesn't allow variable-width regexes in lookbehinds (sigh). But it's possible like this:

```
>>> re.findall("(?:^|(?<=,))[^,]*", "a,b,,c")
['a', 'b', '', 'c']
```

Comment: What should I do if I don't want empty matches, but I want that empty string is returned on two consecutive commas ",,"?

Comment: @msh - Thats a good question. I don't think something like `(?=,,)|.+?(?=,|$)` would be able to get past the two `,,` without consuming at least one comma. Then engine only advances on character on non-consumption.

Comment: @msh: OK, a regex is possible, but quite ugly in comparison to a simple `.split()`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
st='a,b,   c  , d, eeeee'
data=[e.strip() for e in st.split(',')]

print data
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'eeeee']
```

Or use csv:

```
for line in csv.reader(st.splitlines()):
    print line
# ['a', 'b', '   c  ', ' d', ' eeeee']  # strip as you please
```

Or a regex:

```
print re.findall(r'([^,]+)(?:,|$)', st) 
# ['a', 'b', '   c  ', ' d', ' eeeee']
```

---

#### Edit

This does what you are requesting with a regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^,]+|,\s*,', 'a,b,   c  ,, d, eeeee')
['a', 'b', '   c  ', ',,', ' d', ' eeeee']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your entire regex consist of "optional" character consumption before a lookahead assertion.

As the match position advances it can either match something or nothing.
When it matches nothing, the array fills with a `''`.

So `a,b` matches 'a', '', 'b', ''
where the final '' is the end of string (just as `.*$` matches the empty string)